# От куда у меня взялись куки с другого пути?

Tags: php, cookie

При попытке пофиксить один баг на одном проекте, я увидел, что каким-то образом у меня на одном и том же домене два одинаковых кукисов, но с разными путями. Т.е. допустим я сейчас нахожусь на https://example.com/en и я могу там увидеть две одинаковых куки, но которые записаны на разные пути. Может я не правильно понимаю как работают куки, или же консоль разработчика отображает все куки на сервере, или же может в настройке `nginx` что-то такое прописано, что может на это повлиять?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Консоль может показать что угодно. Например если вы делали аяксовый запрос на `/ru` или даже просто картинку оттуда загрузили…

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а, то есть если куки записан на `/en`, то он ведь никак не сможет быть прочитан на `/ru`, верно же? Но он все также может отображаться в консоле, на любом пути домена?

Comment: Прочитать нельзя. Но консоль это совсем другая штука. В ней может быть показано много всего что помогает разработчику, но это не значит что всё это доступно скриптам на странице.